# wso2is 5.3 account recovery using other email addresses

Tags: email, passwords, recovery

I have just implemented wso2is 5.3 and I am looking at setting up the password and username recovery options.

Wso2is is set up with our Active Directory domain as the primary user store. In AD, the 'mail' attribute holds the user's primary email address, and 'otherMailbox' contains additional, external email addresses for the user.

I would like to use the email recovery, but we can't use the primary email, since the password for that account is the password they are trying to reset. We need to have the recovery process use one of the addresses in 'otherMail'.

I can't find anywhere in the documentation where you can define any option for what email is used for the recovery process.

Is the primary email the only one supported for password recovery? How can I tell the password and username recovery process to use a different email?

Thanks

Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is to change the claim mapping for the email address claim in WSO2 to point to the otherMailbox attribute in AD. It properly deals with the multi-valued email address list and for the purposes of password recovery, it sends the notification to all of the listed email addresses.

We then created another claim called Campus Email and pointed it at the mail attribute in AD.

There doesn't seem to be any negative issue with having 'our' email not be the 'primary' email.

Don